# For Loop in Windows Batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've a windows batch script calling another batch every 10 mins. I used a For loop to call the batch and then wait for 10 mins.

---

```
@ECHO OFF
echo %date:~0,10% %time% Running Post To GIM II ...
FOR %%a IN (1,2,3,4,5) DO (
echo %date:~0,10% %time% Starting Post To GIM II ...
CALL D:\Appshares\Autosys\scripts\Sophis\_commonJobWrapper.bat    D:\sophis\Client\UBS_PostToGIMII.exe
echo %date:~0,10% %time% Ending Post To GIM II ...
PING -n 600 127.0.0.1 >NUL 2>&1 
)
```

---

However the inner batch accepts another .exe as a parameter. But the inner batch executes only once and then exits. The inner batch code is like this. Can anybody tell why the loop is always exiting after 1 run?

---

```
@echo off

REM parameter 1 is the program to be called, parameter 2 onwards are additional optional parameters
REM -- Record Time
echo --- JobWrapper Start : %date% %time% ---

REM -- Set starting folder to where application was called from
  cd /d %~dp0
REM -- Set Secure varibales via a securly permissioned file
  if exist _CommonBeginSecure.BAT (call _CommonBeginSecure.BAT)
REM -- Debug mode, start message
  if "%_senddebug%" NEQ "" cscript.exe /NOLOGO %_sendmail% "%_applic% (%_envname%): Autosys job started - %~nx1" "Logfile: %~n1.out" %_senddebug% %_sendfrom%
REM -- Call program passing thru any parameters (currently maximum of 9)
  echo Calling: %1
  call %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
REM -- Error Handling
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto error
goto end

:error

REM -- Send Failed Message
if "%_sendto%" NEQ "" cscript.exe /NOLOGO %_sendmail% "%_applic% (%_envname%): Autosys job FAILED - %~nx1" "Logfile: %~n1.out  (Errorlevel: %2)" %_sendto% %_sendfrom%
exit 1

:end
REM - Debug mode, end message
if "%_senddebug%" NEQ "" cscript.exe /NOLOGO %_sendmail% "%_applic% (%_envname%): Autosys job finished - %~nx1" "Logfile: %~n1.out" %_senddebug% %_sendfrom%
REM -- Record Time 
echo --- JobWrapper End : %date% %time% ---    
exit 0
rem - Notes:
rem %0 = Full name of this job 
rem %~dp0 = Actual path of this job
rem     %~nx0 = Filename of this job
rem     %~n0  = Filename of this job (excluding extension)
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `exit /b errorcode`.

`Exit` command, without /b closes cmd instance. With /b closes the running batch file.

Comment: as an alternative, you can `start` your 'inner batch' instead of `call`ing it. - so if it fails, it will not influence your Loop-Batch

Comment: But then, if no /B is used a new window is created and output goes to it, and if /b is used and no window is created then there is no wait for the second batch to finalize. `exit /b` is simpler and involves less changes.

Comment: @mc_nd: you are definitly right - just a possible alternative :)